# how to prompt for yes or no confirmation in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to create an exit button in flash that when clicked will display "Do you really want to exit?"Yes or No.if yes then a countdown from 10 to 1 then exit and if no it goes back to the previous frame. can anyone please help with the code.It is for Flash actionscript 3. i tired using this

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

Exit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void

    { var req:URLRequest =new URLRequest("javascript:confirm('Are you sure?')");
navigateToURL(req);}
```

I tried this code,it works but the popup opens up a browser page then displays the confirmation dialog,does anyone know how i can adjust this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @B Alfa! Please review the [how to ask guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, if you include code showing what you've tried you are more likely to receive a helpful response.

Comment: Flash doesn't have a built in confirmation box type component. You'll have to make your own.

Comment: Are you using Adobe Flash Professional?

Comment: yes i am using Adobe flash Professional